# Django ORM - Add data from intermediate table

Tags: django, database, join, orm, django-queryset

i have the following many to many data structure in my django rest app:

```
class User(Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    memberships = models.ManyToManyField('Membership', through='UserMembership', related_name='users')

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.name)

class Membership(Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.name)

class UserMembership(Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey('User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    membership = models.ForeignKey('Membership', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

When i want to list all users i get:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "name-a",
    memberships: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "member-a"
        }, ...
    ]
}
```

but i actually want to include the "reason" field

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "name-a",
    memberships: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "member-a",
            reason: "somereason"
        }, ...
    ]
}
```

But how do i modify the queryset?

```
User.objects.all().values('members__usermember')
```

doesnt work unfortunetly...

could anybody support?

EDIT:

Serializers:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'memberships')

class MembershipSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Membership
        fields = ('id', 'name')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the solution to your problem has to do more with how are you serializing the objects that with the queryset itself.

Are you using django-rest-framework, if so, please add the serializers to the response. Otherwise, comment and add the code to view how are you serializing the models.

Edit to add possible serializers:

Try with something similar to this snipped

```
class UserMembershipSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='membership.name')

    class Meta:
        model = UserMembership
        fields = ('reason', 'name')


class UserSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    memberships = UserMembershipSerializer(source='usermembership_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'memberships')
```

Comment: hey i added the requested serializers... can you refer to it?

Comment: Of course, I added some possible modifications to the serializers